# Tensorflow Serving - Not found: Op type not registered 'GatherTree'

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, opennmt

I just a newbie. I have problem when I serving tensorflow model in this case:

I. Using this http://opennmt.net/OpenNMT-tf/quickstart.html to train    the model.

II. Serving the model with following steps:

1. Create docker image with:

`docker build --pull -t $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel -f tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel .`

2. Run docker container:

`docker run --name=tf_container -it $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel`

3. Serving the model:

`tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_name=model_name --model_base_path=/model_file &> result_log &`

III.The *result_log* file content:

````
2019-10-21 02:46:12.840258: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:155] Encountered an error for servable version {name: ente version: 1569320347}: Not found: Op type not registered 'GatherTree' in binary running on 1b79e5fb3ac4. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
2019-10-21 02:46:12.840280: E tensorflow_serving/core/aspired_versions_manager.cc:359] Servable {name: ente version: 1569320347} cannot be loaded: Not found: Op type not registered 'GatherTree' in binary running on 1b79e5fb3ac4. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
2019-10-21 02:46:13.664569: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:280] Unload all remaining servables in the manager.
Failed to start server. Error: Unknown: 1 servable(s) did not become available: {{{name: ente version: 1569320347} due to error: Not found: Op type not registered 'GatherTree' in binary running on 1b79e5fb3ac4. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.}, } ```

I have searched Google and try to update some services, but the problem still here. Anyone have any idea please?

Thanks so much for any suggestions!
````

Answer (score 0):

With the transition to TensorFlow 2.0, the `GatherTree` op that is used in beam search is currently not available in TensorFlow Serving.

- If you exported your model with OpenNMT-tf 1.x, it uses the op `GatherTree` from [`tf.contrib`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/gather_tree) which was removed in recent versions of TensorFlow Serving. You should use a previous version of TensorFlow Serving such as 1.15.0.
- If you exported your model with OpenNMT-tf 2.x, it uses the op `Addons>GatherTree` from [TensorFlow Addons](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons) which is presently not integrated in TensorFlow Serving. This is a [work in progress](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/588). There are currently 2 workarounds:

  - use [`opennmt/tensorflow-serving:2.1.0`](https://hub.docker.com/r/opennmt/tensorflow-serving) which is a custom Serving build that includes this op.
  - disable beam search in OpenNMT-tf by exporting your model with this configuration:

```
params:
  beam_width: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've tried to pull older version using: `docker pull tensorflow/serving:1.15.0` and run a docker container with that image: `docker run --name=tf1150 -it tensorflow/serving:1.15.0`. But inside this container, tensorflow version still 2.0 `TensorFlow ModelServer: 0.0.0+dev.sha.21b257fa
TensorFlow Library: 2.0.0`

Comment: And I try to use older version : 1.14.0 and 1.13.0. But when I run the docker: `docker run --name=tf1140 -it tensorflow/serving:1.14.0`. The result is `E tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:362] FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a filesystem access error: Could not find base path /models/model for servable model`. I can not run the container. Do you have any idea? I am still digging .. . Thank you so much!